# Parse LESS client side

Tags: css, less, client-side

Can I parse LESS client side, and return the results?

I am currently using as recommended in documentation, which is to include less file, and minified less parser afterwards. I want to be able to return the raw css so I can save it as a css file.

I do not want to install node.js and the likes, I want a client side solution.

Comment: for someone with your reputation mistaging is atrocious.

Comment: mistaging? What does that mean?

Comment: @MK.: What do you mean? `less` is the appropriate tag.

Comment: @MK: It would have taken you less time to retag than write that comment.

Comment: On my own computer, I don't mind installing node.js and the likes (I actually use a plugin for sublime editor), but when I am not at my computer, it is not convenient to install things. I want a method that I can use from a non-development computer (or maybe even an iPad).

Comment: @Madmartigan I have no idea what he's talking about so how can I retag?  I came here to see what does the less command have to do with the client side.

Comment: @MK. If you have no idea what he's talking about, how do you know it's mistagged? O.o

Comment: @Madmartigan because when the question has appropriate tags I can always get at least a vague idea what is it about? Like if there was a css tag, for example.

Comment: @MK if you hover your mouse over the less tag for a second, it will explain what the tag is about (Starts CSS preprocessor...). Hopefully this will remove confusion with the linux command `less`. It is unfortunate that there are two computer related things with the same name, but that's the way of the world. Does not cause as much problem as whole Java/Javascript naming thing, which I feel I should get a t-shirt made up to clarify as I am endlessly explaining the difference to people. .-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A look at the [less.js source](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js) brings up the [`Parser`](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js) object. Assuming that `less.js` is included in the page:

```
var data = "@colour: red; #example { background-color: @colour; }",
    parser = new less.Parser({});

parser.parse(data, function (error, root) { 
    // code that handles the parsed data here...
    // e.g.:
    console.log( root.toCSS() ); 
});
```

will output the following to the console:

```
#example {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The constructor for `less.Parser` actually takes series of settings, and I don't understand enough of the internals of LESS to say what might be good to pass (though they are all optional so passing none should just use the defaults).

The `Parser.parse` method takes two parameters: a string containing the LESS file, and a callback that handles the parsed data. The callback receives up to two parameters, an error object (`error`) and an object representing the parsed LESS (`root`). `root` isn't passed if there was a fatal error, and `error` will be `null` if there was no error.

Unfortunately, I can't find any better documentation on the attributes of the error parameter than the place they are set in the source [here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser.js#L226).

Comment: Just what I was looking for, works a treat, thanks. I am a little surprised this is an undocumented feature of the client side script as it is such a fundamental and trivial functionality. This means I can easily use less as source, even when I am offline on my iPad, or working from other computer's with only access to browser based tools. Happy days. Thanks again .~)

Comment: Turns out this method is documented (pretty much identical), but for server side. Happens to work fine on client side too.

Comment: Link to parser code is dead. This is probably? the same thing: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/lib/less/parser/parser.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/y0oss091/1/

```
less.render("p{color: #ff66ff}")
    .then(function(output) {
        console.log(output.css)
    },
  function(error){});
```

Less is loaded from a CDN.

There are many resources out there.
However, I am not sure that client-side use is easier than installing npm and node.

Answer (score -1):

@dbaupp's answer was hugely helpful to me, but I didn't find the error handling to be how described in his answer.

I found the errors to be thrown when parsing less client side rather than being passed to the error parameter meaning you can't react to them within the parse callback.

```
// I too have no idea what to pass to less.Parser
// but none of them seemed very useful for this
// reading through the source
var parser = new less.Parser( {} ),
    toparse = '.foo {color: red;}';

try {
    parser.parse( function ( error, root ) {
        var css = root.toCSS();
        console.log( css );
    } );
} catch ( e ) {
    // if we hit a 404 when importing a less file
    // this is only thrown at the end of all the imports
    // rather than as soon as it find one broken @import
    if ( e.name === 'TypeError' && e.message === "Cannot call method 'toCSS' of undefined" ) {
        // handle typeerror here

    // if there's a parse error
    // assuming your original less file is just some @imports
    // this will also tell you which file contains the error
    } else if ( e.line ) {
        // the url of the imported file
        console.log( e.filename );

        // the line containing the error
        console.log( e.line );

        // this is a 3 item array containing the line with the error
        // +/- 1 line either side
        // e.extract[1] will be your error
        console.log( e.extract );

        // this is the error message
        console.log( e.message );
    } else {
        // it broke some other way
        // I haven't had this happen to me yet
        // so you'll have to figure it out for yourself ;)
    }
}
```

As an example of where this might be useful, my application is adding support for less to [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org), where I can't access anything server side, but can access the site's css and js files. I can parse the less myself and replace the existing css with the freshly parsed less meaning I'm the only one who needs js enabled for it to work :)