# having difficulties with less

Tags: css, less

I'am new with LESS and i'm trying to sort things out. This is my question for example i have a less file that looks like this

style.less

```
.FontAttr(@f-color: red, @f-weight: bold, @f-size: 12px) {
   color: @f-color;
   font-weight: @f-weight;
   font-size: @f-size;
}
```

from what i know i can use this like this in style.less

```
.fakelinkfont {
   .FontAttr(red, bold, 14px);
}
```

then use .fakelinkfont like this in my actual page

```
<div class="fakelinkfont">Some Characters</div>
```

my question is can i use .FontAttr() {...} in my actual page and not in style.less or do i even doing everything correct. BTW i'm new with this so bear with me thank in advance.

Comment: Did not understand what you mean by use *`.FontAttr(){}` in my actual page*. If you mean assigning `FontAttr` as a class to an element then it is not possible. If you mean writing the whole thing within a `style` tag in your page then it is possible but not recommended as it would require client-side compilation of Less code.

Comment: @Harry, what i mean by using .FontAttr(){..} in actual page is that instead of writing .fakelinkfont { .FontAttr(red, bold, 14px); } in my style.less can i write it in my actual web page and not in style.less

Comment: http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746756/

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

```
.fakelinkfont {
   .FontAttr(red, bold, 14px);
}
```

Gets compiled to:

```
.fakelinkfont {
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

And that is what browser uses.
You can try using [client side](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage) less.js file, but I wouldn't recomend to use it in production.